# elastic search matching issue

Tags: elasticsearch, pattern-matching, match

I am having an issue with finding results when I make an elastic search query. I have verified that the index has the search elements.

This is my query. The idea is to find all elements that have "ale" in whole or in part on the LOGIN, FIRST_NAME and LAST_NAME fields. I don't have any entry that has a first name or last name or login with the exact term "ale". However, I do have entries indexed that have part of the first name or last name or login as "ale".

I think I am doing something wrong, but I am not sure how I can accomplish this.

Please advise.

```
SEARCH: {
  "query" : {
    "query_string" : {
      "query" : "ale",
      "fields" : [ "FIRST_NAME^10.0", "LAST_NAME^10.0", "LOGIN^10.0"]
    }
  },
  "_source" : {
    "includes" : [ "FIRST_NAME", "LAST_NAME", "LOGIN"],
   }
}
```

Comment: it should be "ale*". wildcard search in query_string

Answer (score 0):

```
{
"query" : {
"query_string" : {
  "query" : "*ale*",
  "fields" : [ "FIRST_NAME^10.0", "LAST_NAME^10.0", "LOGIN^10.0"]
  }
},
"_source" : {
"includes" : [ "FIRST_NAME", "LAST_NAME", "LOGIN"],
 }
}
```

This will work as `like`  operator in `sql` which is what you exactly want.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, very kind of you. it worked for me.

Comment: Hello, I have one more question to this problem. When special characters are present in the input, the search fails. For example, if my input is "query" : "(McO", I get an exception due to the left paranthesis in the input string. The exception goes like org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchPhaseExecutionException Was expecting one of:
    <AND> ...
    <OR> ...
    <NOT> ...
    "+" ...
    "-" ...

Comment: You need to escape special characters before passing it to query string like \\McO